# img tag stretching, aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

**Say i have an image.**

It can not be wrapped in divs or any other tags.

Can three images of different sizes be placed in stand-alone IMG tags that have a maximum height of 500px with its width being stretched to a given size (1920 in this case) yet the image be placed v-center with vertical overflow hidden?

**As in:**

> img1 1504x500 stretched to 1920x638.3 yet only 1920x500 shows centered
>   img2 1546x500 stretched to 1920x621   yet only 1920x500 shows centered
>   img3 1793x500 stretched to 1920x535.4 yet only 1920x500 shows centered

Comment: Use a background image. Otherwise you have to put a div around your image and hide the overflow and thrn position your photo correctly.

Comment: set `width:100%` to `img` tag

Comment: Quite simply... no. An image tag alone can't achieve what you're attempting to do. You need to wrap it inside another tag

Comment: Dennis Thank you for your input, but that's where the problem is at the moment. I am playing around with angular2, at the moment with carousels. The problem is that it won't display an image unless and IMG tag is used. Wrapping said IMG tag in anything will again not display anything.

Was just wondering if the IMG tag is that rusty and not robust to change.
Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you Nathan. Thought i was going crazy :\

Comment: was carousal created by you? or else? you can change js file with however output you want.

Comment: Hi Pathak. No, the carousel was not created by me, and it was ported from standard bootstrap to angular2-bootstrap by the people that made angular. It is a little too wonky at the moment. I tried to look through the sources but it does not look like there is much to be done by me at the moment. Thank you.